# unable to map subdomain in local host webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webserver, wildcard-subdomain

I am developing a web application using Asp.net mvc framework with concept of  sub domain for community.

I have implement concept of wild card mapping of domain like *.example.com.  To test concept in vs 2008 i edited hosts file and add some sub domain like

127.0.0.1  a.localhost

127.0.0.1  b.localhost

When i request url  http://a.localhost:1760/ i get error

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://a.localhost:1760/

The following error was encountered:

```
Unable to determine IP address from host name for a.localhost
```

The dnsserver returned:

```
Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
```

This means that:

The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. 
 Check if the address is correct.

What i should  do to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost can't have subdomains - it's a reserved DNS name that simply doesn't support them. You could, instead, use a.myhost.example and b.myhost.example, but be aware that Cassini, the VS development web server doesn't understand host headers.

Comment: So, What is the procedure for testing subdomain created dynamically in localhost.

Comment: Thanks For Your Quick Reply.plz Suggest Me how to test application with sub domain in development environment?

Comment: Thanks blowdart , i Got solution.